# Could "Could not find relationship target File[]" be triggered by a cron resource?

Tags: file, cron, resources, puppet

Is it possible that the cron resource type uses the file resource type underneath? I'm asking because I'm trying to debug this error:

> could not find relationship target File[]

and the manifests that apply to this particular node contain no File resource type (that I haven't already verified work on other nodes). However, it does contain a questionable `cron`, which when commented out, doesn't generate that error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: That the manifests for the node do not declare any `File` resource would indeed be consistent with an error such as you describe.  But the proximal problem is that some resource -- apparently the `Cron` resource in question -- declares a relationship with an undeclared `File`.  That might or might not appear directly in the `Cron` resource's own declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what was specified by ncracker, it would seem that there is a file resource being referenced somewhere.  If it wasn't directly a part of the cron that you commented out, you could look for a Cron { require => File[$somevar] } call elsewhere in your code.

That is a way that is sometimes used to tie together default resource behavior.